# Why there is no position of H and He in Lothar Meyer's curve?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-table

I see Alkali metals occupy the peak points. $\ce{H}$ is not an Alkali metal. There's no $\ce{H}$ in the graph. So no point before $\ce{Li}$.

Inert gases occupy place on the ascending portion of graph.

As there is no graphical line before $\ce{Li}$, where can $\ce{He}$ be put? There's no place for $\ce{He}$.

But why there's no plot for $\ce{H}$?

Comment: There are two options. Maybe the plot was drawn by the hand of a genius many years ago, and can't be reproduced. But then again, maybe the graph represents **actual physical quantities** that may be looked up for all elements. Well... which will it be?

Comment: The question seems a bit ill defined. Meyer was working during the time that the modern periodic table was created. Chemists were still fumbling around trying to find the overall pattern for the elements. Lothar Meyer seem to have published several curves of atomic volume versus atomic mass. Are you referring to one of his such graphs in particular, or a like graph that can be constructed with modern data?

Answer (score 2):

A German chemist, Julius Lothar Meyer was contemporary and competitor of Russian chemist Dmitri Mendeleev to draw up the first periodic table of chemical elements. In 1864, he published the first version of [his periodic table](https://chemistrygod.com/lothar-meyer-periodic-table) through his book Die modernen Theorien der Chemie. This abbreviated version of a periodic table consisted of 28 elements, about half of the known elements, arranged from the left to right classifying by their properties (mainly their valences) as shown below:

$$
\bf{\text{Lothar Meyer's 1864 table}}\\
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Valance}  & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2  \\
\hline
\text{Element} & - & - & - & - & \ce{Li} = 7.03 & \ce{Be} = 9.3   \\
\hline
\text{ Element} & \ce{C} = 12.0  & \ce{N} = 14.04  & \ce{O} = 16.00  & \ce{F} = 19.0  & \ce{Na} = 23.05 & \ce{Mg} = 24.0   \\
\hline
\text{ Element} & \ce{Si} = 28.5  & \ce{P} = 31.0  & \ce{S} = 32.07  & \ce{Cl} = 35.46  & \ce{K} = 39.13 & \ce{Ca} = 40.0   \\
\hline
\text{ Element} & -  & \ce{As} = 75.0  & \ce{Se} = 78.8  & \ce{Br} = 79.97  & \ce{Ru} = 85.4 & \ce{Sr} = 87.6   \\
\hline
\text{ Element} & \ce{Sn} = 117.6  & \ce{Sb} = 120.6  & \ce{Te} = 128.3  & \ce{I} = 126.8  & \ce{Cs} = 133.0 & \ce{Ba} = 137.1   \\
\hline
\text{ Element} & \ce{Pb} = 207.0  & \ce{Bi} = 208.0  & -  & -  & \ce{Ti} = 204.0 & -   \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

It is evident from this periodic table that Meyer had arranged the elements not only with their increasing atomic weights, but also arranged them according to their valencies. For example, the first column contain the elements $\ce{C, Si, Sn}$, and $\ce{Pb}$, all of which form tetrahydrides ($\ce{CH4, SiH4, SnH4}$, and $\ce{PbH4}$) when combined with hydrogen. Thus, their valency is 4. Similarly, the elements of the second column, $\ce{N, O, F, Na}$, and $\ce{Mg}$, since their valency is 3, would combine with hydrogen to form corresponding trihydrides such as $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{PH3}$, and so on. Meyer's grouping of elements based on their valency, and this type of grouping is based on the chemical properties of the elements.

Later, Meyer has plotted the graph of the atomic volume (molar volume) vs atomic weight of elements, which is called Lothar Meyer's  Curve:

[image: Lothar Meyer's Curve]

He has not plotted hydrogen on the curve probably because it is considered to be a specific element, which is able to react with most of elements to form hydrides (see above). On the other hand, in the case of helium, it wasn't discovered at the time of Meyer's (technically speaking). The existence of helium was first discovered in 1864, when a French astronomer, Jules Janssen has detected a bright yellow line with a wavelength of $\pu{587.49 nm}$ in the spectrum of the chromosphere of the Sun during the solar eclipse. Around 1870, when Meyer plotted his curve, $\ce{He}$ wasn't still discovered on the Earth (the year of that discovery was not until 1895). Also, the discoveries of all noble gasses have been done after Meyer's time and none of them were in his curve.

However, the supposed places of two elements in question, $\ce{H}$  and $\ce{He}$, have been plotted by me in the original Lothar Meyer's curve for convenience (see scatted yellow lines). As evident, there is no maximum (with $\ce{H}$) or minimum as a series of maxima and minima shown by other elements (alkali metals at the peaks). The absence of all noble gasses in the curve is justified by Mendeleev's Periodic Table, first published in 1869:

[image: Mendeleev Periodic Table]